# Unable to send POST value using AJAX

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, post

I have two seperate files, one bargraph.html, and the other data.php.

Bargraph.html is as follows:

```
<form method="POST" name="dataform" action="">
  <select name="data1" id="data1-value">
    <option value="DateRecorded">DateRecorded</option>
    <option value="InletVoltage">InletVoltage</option>
    <option value="InletCurrent">InletCurrent</option>
    <option value="ActivePower">ActivePower</option>
    <option value="PowerFactor">PowerFactor</option>
    <option value="SystemID">SystemID</option>
    </select>
    <select name="data2" id ="data2-value">
    <option value="DateRecorded">DateRecorded</option>
    <option value="InletVoltage">InletVoltage</option>
    <option value="InletCurrent">InletCurrent</option>
    <option value="ActivePower">ActivePower</option>
    <option value="PowerFactor">PowerFactor</option>
    <option value="SystemID">SystemID</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#data1-value').change(function(){
        var data1Value = $(this).val();
$('#data2-value').change(function(){
        var data2Value = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'data.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {data1, data2: data1Value, data2Value},
        success:function(data){ 
            alert(data); 
        }, 
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }, 
        complete: function(){
        }
    });
})});
</script>
```

A section of data.php is as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['data1'])) {
    $opp1 = $_POST['data1'];
    $opp2 = $_POST['data2'];
} else {
    $opp1 = 'SystemID';
    $opp2 = 'ApparentPower';
}

$sql = "SELECT $opp1, $opp2 FROM RaritanMachineDataa";
```

In my bargraph.html I have two drop down menus. I want the options selected from the drop down menu to be sent using AJAX to my data.php file to perform a select statement on my database.

Currently when I run my code, it's returning an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: data1 is not defined
```

And this is pointing to line 53:

```
url: 'data.php',
```

Could someone give me some assistance on this please as I do not know how to fix this.

UPDATE: (Code below):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#dataform').submit(function(e){
        var data1Value = $("#data1").val();
        var data2Value = $("#data2").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'data.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {data1, data1Value, data2: data2Value},
        success:function(data){ 
            alert(data); 
        }, 
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }, 
        complete: function(){
        }
    });
})});
</script>
```

Returning error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

On line (at the 2nd last line)

```
})});
```

I have tried removing the bracket, and curly bracket but cannot seem to get it to run. What have I done wrong? Thanks for the assistance

UPDATE (Submit button not POSTING data):

```
        <option value="PowerFactor">PowerFactor</option>
    <option value="SystemID">SystemID</option>
  </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#dataform').submit(function(e){
        var data1Value = $("#data1").val();
        var data2Value = $("#data2").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'data.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {data1, data1Value, data2: data2Value},
        success:function(data){ 
            alert(data); 
        }, 
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }, 
        complete: function(){
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: `data: {data1, data2: data1Value, data2Value},` - where is data1 and data2 defined/set?

Comment: it should be like `data: {data1 : data1Value, data2: data2Value},`

Comment: also the `change` evt handlers are weirdly nested..

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT $opp1, $opp2 FROM RaritanMachineDataa"` this is a ***very*** bad idea. Don't inject variables directly into the query!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Error is here:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'data.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {data1, data2: data1Value, data2Value}, <-- Your error is here
```

Change this line to:

```
 data: {data1: data1Value, data2: data2Value}
```

Also I've just noticed that you are doing this

```
('#data1-value').change(function(){
    var data1Value = $(this).val();
     $('#data2-value').change(function(){
        var data2Value = $(this).val();
```

I don't believe that `$('#data2-value').change` is ever getting called. I suggest you handle the submission of the form after both values have been set!!!

With @Devpro comment, your dropdown menus now need to have an assigned id in order for this submit function to work

**HTML**

```
 <select name="data1" id="data1-value"> to  <select id="data1" name="data1" id="data1-value">
 <select name="data2" id ="data2-value"> to  <select id="data2" name="data2" id ="data2-value">
```

**JQuery**

```
 $('#dataform').submit(function(e) {
       var data1Value = $("#data1").val();
       var data2Value = $("#data2").val();

       //ajax submit with my edits
       $.ajax....

       e.preventDefault(); //prevent page refresh.
  });
```

Comment: I changed it to "data: {data1: data1Value, data2: data2Value}," and same error returns

Comment: Okay where should I move the function to? Should I place the data2-value function in my ajax function? Or is there a better way of running that function?

Comment: i dont think so, it will work `var data1Value = $(this).val();
       var data2Value = $(this).val();`

Comment: Which one @devpro?

Comment: these 2 lines: `var data1Value = $(this).val();
       var data2Value = $(this).val();` u must need to add dropdown IDs here..

Comment: I meant in his original post he had `$('#data2-value').change` nested in `$('#data1-value').change`, so if he only changed data2 value, then it wouldn't be seen

Comment: I didn't spot that...nice one, is the other parts of my edits okay??

Comment: How am I inserting the values into that function? Is it something like: var data1Value = $('#data1-value').val(); ?

Comment: It's done Danny. This should solve your question. Thanks @devpro for the spotting

Comment: @Danny if this answer helped you, accept the answer, as someone else might have the same problem as you!

Comment: You need to remove an extra `})`, thats why your code is throwing an error at that line

Comment: That fixed that error however now, when I choose from both drop down lists, it does not submit the values to data.php file so now I need to debug that...  :)

Comment: You need to add an submit button!!

Comment: you need to add `<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>` after the last select field

Comment: Okay and I also need to add a submit function of some sort to the ajax so it works when user hits "submit" right? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Also don't forget to add `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the page refreshing, so that you can see your submitted data. You can already find that part in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188991/discussion-between-kebab-programmer-and-danny).